# 6 week old suddenly sleeping 6-7 hour stretch at night

Tags: sleep, newborn

It has been 3 days since his six week birthday, and our son has suddenly managed to sleep a 6, 6.5 and 7.5 (and counting, as I write this) hour block each respective night.

***Update:** I picked him up at the 8 hour mark. His eyes were open but he was very docile, he only cried from the cold when I opened his clothes to change his diaper. Based on the sounds from the baby monitor alone, I wouldn't have said he was awake. After feeding, he fell asleep almost immediately after he burped.*

Before then, we could manage somewhere between a 3.5 to 4.5 hour stretch once a night.

Since about a week and a half ago, he did stop sleeping long hours during the day, often staying down for a nap less than an hour at a time, except when sleeping while being held.

From what I read, this kind of long night sleeping is attributed to a 6 *month* old, not a 6 week old.

So far, he has tracked reasonably well for growth and weight, he actually had quite the spurt at around 4 weeks, gaining 400g and 2cm in 9 days, which I am told is a lot by the pediatrician.

I'm just wondering if this is a blessing or a cause for concern. Should I be waking him up?

Comment: Have you talked to your paediatrician about it?

Comment: @nick012000: We went to the pediatrician the day before it started happening because he _wasn't_ sleeping very well. It took us a while to figure out the right balance of feeding/meds to solve cramps/diarrhaea issues. An appt takes a few days and I need to book leave from work, and it seems a bit futile to now go back and basically go "now he sleeps well. What now?" That's not to say that I wouldn't take him if necessary, but I'm rather trying to figure out whether there is any indication to do so, as sleeping _more_ doesn't strike me as cause for concern. Hence the question to make sure.

Comment: Let sleeping dogs lie. And sleeping babies even more so.

Comment: Does he seem alert when he's awake during the day? If so then I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: He seems a bit behind on the curve at starting to vocalize and interact with us (my wife tells me that should be happening by week 6), but he is perfectly awake during the day.

Comment: If your baby is following the growth curves, let him sleep. This is probably your first, no? Babies don't follow rules. Don't worry if he's s bit behind in babbling, tracking, etc. This is what your doctor is for, and he should have an 8 week visit coming up soon. When he gives you his first belly-laugh, you'll forget everything you worried about. Enjoy!

Comment: To give you another data point, our child was sleeping through the entire night after only 1 week and none of the medical professionals involved were worried about that in any way.

Comment: Humorous hint: If you hit the jackpot in the baby-sleeps-through-the-night lottery, please refrain from elaborating on this when talking to parents whose (older) babies are on the other side of the normal distribution curve. Their sleep-deprived brains will have difficulties handling that information in a positive and polite manner. Been there… not proud of my reactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The age at which a child starts sleeping through the night varies significantly: some start doing it when they are only a few weeks old, whereas the parent "horror stories" tell us about the children who make it through the night for the first time when they were more than a year old!

There is a combination of physiological and psychological factors at play here:

- *physiological* - a newborn's stomach is simply too small to keep enough food to keep them through the night. As the child (and their stomach) grows it can sleep longer. A rule of thumb is that a baby of more than 5 kilograms is capable of sleeping through the night (physiologically).
- *psychological* - a newborn is unaware of the difference between the day and the night, and needs time to learn it. Some consider the *unconsolable crying* in the evenings, that takes place between 4-12 weeks of age, as the first manifestation of the insinctive peur of darkness. This is by no means a generally accepted explanation, but this is again well before 6 months, mentioned in the OP.

Let me also note that the transition from waking every 3 hours to sleeping throughout a night may be indeed a very sharp one.

Finally, note that "6 months" mentioned in the OP is a rather advanced stage - by then the baby acquires lots of other (arguably more complex skills): holding their head, sitting (with a support), turning over in bed, smiling, etc. 6 months is also a time when the diversification of food may have already started. Moreover, at 6 months the child *may start again waking at night*, e.g., because of teething pains.

Comment: He's actually 4.5kg right now, so somewhat under the rule of thumb, but the 8 hour sleep seems to be an odd one out, he slept 6 hours last night. Thank you for the information, it helps a lot to stop us worrying!